# liquibase change existing changelog from mysql to mssql

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring-boot, liquibase

I have all my liquibase changelogs with respect to MySQL database now we are planning to move to MSSQL so when I try to run the existing changelogs which is working fine for MySQL is failing for MSSQL. Is there any configuration in liquibase to handle database migration?

getting below error when I run changelogs on MSSQL

addAfterColumn is not allowed on mssql

Answer (score 0):

you can use [dbms](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/changelog-formats.html) attribute and configure changelogs to be executed only on given databases.